# Перегрузка компонента в react ts

Tags: reactjs, typescript

Всем привет! У меня есть компонент, в котором я хочу реализовать такую схему: 1) или передаются только два "основных" пропса: `icon` и `title`, 2) или я передаю все 5 пропсов: `icon`, `title`, `expanded`, `onOpen`, `onClose`, если хочу использовать ручную настройку для экспанда. Я попытался реализовать это с помощью перегрузок и у меня даже получилось, если передать только первые 2, то все будет норм, если добавить, к примеру, `expanded`, то появляется ошибка, типо, нет такой перегрузки, поэтому нужно добавить еще два: `onOpen` и  `onClose`. Но, дело в том, что в таком случае не появляются подсказки(автодополнение) от ide(webstorm), а хотелось бы. И вот я не понимаю, что сделал не так.

```
interface ExpandingContainerProps {
  icon: ReactNode;
  title: ReactNode;
}

interface ManuallyExpanding{
  expanded: boolean;
  onOpen: () => void;
  onClose: () => void;
}

function ExpandingContainer(props: PropsWithChildren<ExpandingContainerProps>): ReactElement;
function ExpandingContainer(props: PropsWithChildren<ExpandingContainerProps & ManuallyExpanding>): ReactElement;
function ExpandingContainer(props: PropsWithChildren<ExpandingContainerProps & Partial<ManuallyExpanding>>): ReactElement {...}
```

Comment: Мб третья перегрузка все портит? Если 2 кейса почему перегрузок 3?

Answer (score 0):

Если icon и title основные, то пусть будут обязательными.

```
interface ExpandingContainerProps {
icon: ReactNode;
title: ReactNode;
expanded?: boolean;
onOpen?: () => void;
onClose?: () => void;
}
```